# jQuery validation plugin not work in ajax post data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I need to validate my from using jQuery validation plugin before send data using `$.ajax` method. I have this code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
      name: {
        required: true,
        rangelength: [4, 20],
      },
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true,
      },
      message: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
      if (grecaptcha.getResponse() == '') {
        $('#reCaptchaError').html('<p>Recaptcha Empty</p>');
      }
      else {
        $('#reCaptchaError').hide();
        $("#ajax-1").click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault(); // avoid submitting the form here
          $("#ajax-form-msg1").html("<img src='<?php echo RELATIVE_PATH. '/templates/'. TEMPLATENAME; ?>'/img/loading.gif'/>");
          var formData = $("#ajaxform").serialize();
          var URL = $("#ajaxform").attr("action");
          $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            crossDomain: true,
            xhrFields: {
              withCredentials: true
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
              if (data == "yes") {
                $("#ajax-form-msg1").html('
<div class="alert alert-success">' + data + '</div>
');
                $("#form-content").modal('show');
                $(".contact-form").slideUp();
              }
              else {
                $("#ajax-form-msg1").html('' + data + '');
              }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              $("#ajax-form-msg1").html('
<div class="alert alert-danger">
AJAX Request Failed<br/> textStatus=' + textStatus + ', errorThrown=' + errorThrown + '</code></pre>');
            }
          });
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="" id="ajax-msg1"></div>
<form id="myform" action="load.php">
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" id="my_token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
<button type="submit" name="submit" id="ajax-1">Send</button>
</form>
```

But in action my form not work and not send data!! how do fix this problem ?!

Comment: At a guess, it acts as if your `grecaptcha.getResponse()` is returning empty, but you haven't provided enough detail to make it easy to troubleshoot your problem. What errors are you seeing in your browser console? What behavior are you seeing, with what inputs? What pieces of the puzzle have you left out in an effort to simplify (e.g., there is no `grecaptcha` object referenced in your code--what is that)?

Answer (score 2):

you are serializing an Id that doesn't exist in this context

```
var formData = $("#ajaxform").serialize();
```

You should be using this:

```
var formData = $("#myform").serialize();
```

Also probably you should be using a `async: false` and should keep in mind that `success:` is deprecated in newer versions. Try use .done() instead!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                rangelength: [4, 20],
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
            },
            message: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            if (grecaptcha.getResponse() == '') {
                $('#reCaptchaError').html('<p>Recaptcha Empty</p>');
            } else {
                $('#reCaptchaError').hide();
                $("#ajax-1").click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault(); // avoid submitting the form here
                    $("#ajax-form-msg1").html("<img src='<?php echo RELATIVE_PATH. '/templates/'. TEMPLATENAME; ?>'/img/loading.gif'/>");
                    var formData = $("#myform").serialize();
                    var URL = $("#myform").attr("action");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: URL,
                        type: "POST",
                        data: formData,
                        crossDomain: true,
                        xhrFields: {
                            withCredentials: true
                        },
                        async: false
                    }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        if (data == "yes") {
                            $("#ajax-form-msg1").html(' < div class = "alert alert-success" > ' + data + ' < /div>');
                            $("#form-content").modal('show'); $(".contact-form").slideUp();
                        } else {
                            $("#ajax-form-msg1").html('' + data + '');
                        }
                    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        $("#ajax-form-msg1").html(' < div class = "alert alert-danger" >AJAX Request Failed < br / > textStatus = ' + textStatus + ', errorThrown = ' + errorThrown + ' < /code></pre > ');
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```